# Geoserver Sld Not Working Correctly

Tags: openlayers, gis, geoserver, sld

I work with Geoserver and I use SLD for my layers

my sld file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Without Label</sld:Name>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>10000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>70000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#CC3300</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>8</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>With Label</sld:Name>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>10000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#CC3300</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>12</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
          <sld:TextSymbolizer>
            <sld:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>str_name</ogc:PropertyName>
            </sld:Label>
            <sld:Font>
              <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Times</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">14</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Font>
            <sld:LabelPlacement>
              <sld:PointPlacement>
                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                  <sld:AnchorPointX>0.5</sld:AnchorPointX>
                  <sld:AnchorPointY>0.0</sld:AnchorPointY>
                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                <sld:Displacement>
                  <sld:DisplacementX>0</sld:DisplacementX>
                  <sld:DisplacementY>5</sld:DisplacementY>
                </sld:Displacement>
              </sld:PointPlacement>
            </sld:LabelPlacement>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#CC0000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:TextSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

But sometimes labels of points show/hide alternately . For example

Zoom 16

[image]

Zoom 17

[image]

Zoom 18

[image]

This scenario and my SLD is not same . Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your map tiled? If so, the labels might be disappearing because they cross the tile boundaries (as the code cannot reliably predict if the other part of the label will show up in the nearby tile).

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes Map tiled , I am testing now according to your suggestion